# SQL query to join two tables without common column in oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables `employee` and `job_role` as below. I need to write a SQL query to find designation of each employee by joining this table.

Input Table

**Employee**

```
e_id    e_name  Salary
-----------------------
1       ABC     1000
2       CDE     2000
3       GHI     3500
4       JKL     5000
5       MNO     4000
6       XYZ     3000
```

**Job_role**

```
Designation   Sal_min   Sal_max
-------------------------------
Associate      1000      2000
Lead           2001      3000
Manager        3001      5000
```

Problem: if salary from `employee` table is in the range `sal_min` to `sal_max`, find the designation

Desired output:

```
e_id    e_name  Salary  Designation
-----------------------------------    
 1      ABC     1000    Associate
 2      CDE     2000    Associate
 3      GHI     3500    Manager
 4      JKL     5000    Manager
 5      MNO     4000    Manager
 6      XYZ     3000    Lead
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ON` clause can consist of other operations than `=`. Here you can use `<=` and `>=` (or `BETWEEN` if you like).

```
SELECT E.E_ID,
       E.E_NAME,
       JR.DESIGNATION
       FROM EMPLOYEE E
            LEFT JOIN JOB_ROLE JR
                      ON JR.SAL_MIN <= E.SALARY
                         AND JR.SAL_MAX >= E.SALARY;
```

(Note: I used `LEFT JOIN` for the case that there are any employees where the salary doesn't match. I guessed you rather want to see them with a `NULL` designation than not at all.)

Comment: Thanks mate for your quick reply, i was missing that condition in ON clause. (Y)